# DateOnly and TimeOnly mapping to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

When working with dates, I have been using [DateTime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) type in SQL Server to store C# [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0).

.NET 6 has introduced new structs such as [DateOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0) and [TimeOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly?view=net-6.0). I assume these should be mapped to [Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Are there any corner cases when the conversion wouldn't be valid? Are these types fully compatible?

Comment: They can be mapped, whether they should be mapped is probably a matter of opinion. Currently there is nothing out of the box for this in EF Core ([discussion  here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24507)) or SqlClient (e.g. No GetDateOnly method), or razor (`<input type="time" />` still uses `TimeSpan` for the type). As such I personally have decided that `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` do not add enough value for me to introduce all the additional conversions. I will reassess when further support is added. This is of course entirely subjective. YMMV.

Comment: The new classes still have the same date/time values.  The only differences is the new classes add compare methods so you can easily compare two dates/times.

Comment: @jdweng DateOnly uses an integer to store the date and so uses only half the size that DateTime uses.

Answer (score 2):

When saving time in SQL Server, for instance time(7), with retrieving the column data via a SqlDataReader, the value is returned as a TimeSpan.

This is not an equal conversion. To convert to a TimeOnly instance however, you can parse the stringyfied TimeSpan.

```
TimeOnly.Parse({timespanvalue}.ToString());
```

Not extremely elegant, but something to consider when dealing with TimeOnly and sql server time.